# Adding inherited class, derived from child form

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005, windows-forms-designer

I created a base form (baseForm) which sets the color etc. for all the other forms. Then I created an other form, derived from baseForm, lets call it childForm. Now I want to derive an other form from this childForm, and thus inherit all the settings, buttons, etc from the childForm and baseForm. But after adding this new inherited form, derived from childForm, the only thing I see in design view is one large line of HTML code...

Does someone know an answer to this?

Comment: will you please provide more information ?

Comment: Well, this is all I can give, it describes my problem: I create a windows form in VisualBasic (baseForm). Then I created an other form (childForm), which is an inherited form from baseForm. No problem until now, I can design my form just as always in the design view. Now I created an other form (newForm), which is also an inherited form, but this newForm is inherited from childForm. When I want to design this form in the design view, I see this: <html><head><META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type.... and the rest of this HTML-code, instead of my form. But I want to see my form, so that I can design it.

Comment: are you dealing with Web Form or WinForms ?

Comment: Build your solution and try again. i tried the same for winform and its working for me.

Comment: I did the clean and rebuild solution, but still this stupid HTML code... even rebooted my system

Comment: @SonalSatpute I'm dealing with winforms

Comment: Even more frustrating: When debugging and I call this form to open, it shows the form as it's supposed to look. Now I want this in my design view too :(

Comment: @SonalSatpute I don't have any usefull code to share. This is what I did. In my solution I choose Add->Windows Form. I designed that form and that's my baseForm. then agian I choose Add-> Windows Form-> inherited form. In the inheritance picker I picked baseForm. I designed it, and that's my childForm. Once agian I choose Add->Windows Form->inherited form. Now in Inheritance picker I picked childForm. should work fine, as it shows the form when debugging, but it doesn't show up in design view... code looks good like: public partial class frmRectangular : Inertia_Calculator._frmCalculationsBase

Comment: where CalculationsBase is childForm

Comment: @SonalSatpute I see that I'm receiving a warning: Warning 1 There is already a command handler for the menu command '5efc7975-14bc-11cf-9b2b-00aa00573819 : 17'.

Comment: The solution to my problem is a very silly one... In the childForm, which I tried to inherit, I used the LineShape from the Visual Basic Powerpacks [1]. Once I deleted these lines, the inheritenace was no problem...


  [1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb735936.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem: In the childForm, which I tried to inherit, I used the LineShape from the Visual Basic Powerpacks [1]. Once I deleted these lines, the inheritenace was no problem... [1]: msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb735936.aspx